# Atlas: Type does not conform to protocol ATLParticipant

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, atlas

I am trying to integrate Layer alongwith Atlas into my project. I am working on Swift 2.2. I have made a swift class which should conform to ATLParticipant protocol but Xcode is throwing an error,

Type 'ConversationParticipant' does not conform to protocol 'ATLParticipant'

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. The code is:

```
import Atlas
import Foundation

class ConversationParticipant: NSObject, ATLParticipant {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var fullName: String?
    var participantIdentifier: String?

    var avatarImageURL: NSURL?
    var avatarImage: UIImage?
    var avatarInitials: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: You are missing the `displayName` and `userID` Strings. You need to provide them because [the protocol requires it](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Protocols/ATLParticipant.h)

Comment: wow!! Amazing Kametrixom!!.. It worked.. thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `displayName` and `userID` Strings. You need to provide them because [the protocol requires it](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Protocols/ATLParticipant.h).